# How can we display * for every character we enter ( password prompt ) using system calls in linux?

Tags: c, linux

I am writing C code for 'password prompt' .  I need to display * for every character the user enters . But I am not supported with **getch()**. So , I tried system calls .Example ,

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    system("stty -echo");
    scanf("%c", &a[i]);
    system("stty echo");
    printf("*");
}
```

But it does not print * immediately when we enter a char.

Any other way to achieve this ???

Comment: Console application? GUI application? What have you tried so far? What worked, and what didn't work?

Comment: In what context? Do you want the input to be rewritten or do you want a specific program to display a character differently? Maybe you just want to remap your keyboard layout?

Comment: I have edited and have shown you the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use non-canonical mode without echo.

[See an example here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Noncanon-Example.html)

In  this example, I modified the following lines

```
else
    putchar (c);
```

with

```
else
{
    putchar (c+1);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to reproduce the whole example (and/or just show your whole code) in case that link goes dead in the future.